# jQuery div with Infinite slide show (non stop, Like StarWars)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I try to make an infinite and auto scroll (a little bit to the starwars generic way) in text in a div.
The current code works but the result is not fluid at all .

I do not understand why and I would like this to be fluid.

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $(".slideshow ul").animate({marginTop:-20}, 500, function(){
            $(this).css({marginTop:0}).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
        })
    }, 500);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(function(){
       setInterval(function(){
          $(".slideshow ul").animate({marginTop:-20}, 500, function(){
             $(this).css({marginTop:0}).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
         })
       }, 500);
    });

    
    });
```

```css
body { 
  background: url(img/1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.head {
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);
}

.users {
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding-top: 20px; 
 height: 400px;

 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);

}

#suscrib {
 height: 45px;
 font-size: 15px !important;
}


.slideshow {

   width: 200px;
   height: 370px;
   overflow: hidden;
   /*border: 3px solid #F2F2F2;*/
}

.slideshow ul {
    /* 4 images donc 4 x 100% */
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   padding:0; margin:0;
   list-style: none;
}
.slideshow li {
   color: red;
   font-family: 'Satisfy';

   font-size: 15px;
}


.thanks {
 margin-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Dancing Script';
 font-size: 40px;
 color: red;
}

#ombre {
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 43px #000 !important;
}

h1 {
 padding-top: 80px;
 opacity: 1 !important;
 z-index: 10;
}

#logo {
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>


  
 <body>
  


   <div class="row">
       <div class="users col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5" id="ombre">
        <div class="slideshow col-lg-12 ">
         <ul id="pushme">
              <li> <div id='suscrib'> User user  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div id='suscrib'> User user2  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div id='suscrib'> User user3  </div>  </li>
                          <li> <div id='suscrib'> User user4  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div id='suscrib'> User user  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div id='suscrib'> User user  </div>  </li>
                          <li> <div id='suscrib'> User user  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div id='suscrib'> User user  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div id='suscrib'> User user  </div>  </li>
                          <li> <div id='suscrib'> User user10  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div id='suscrib'> User user  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div id='suscrib'> User user  </div>  </li>
         </ul>
        </div>

       </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

EDIT : Check the new snippet
Thanks a lot !

Comment: can you set up a fiddle please?

Comment: You are moving it it half second intervals. So it moves until the interval times out, stops, and then starts again each time the Interval times out. This is producing your jumpy animation.  Please set up a fiddle so that we can present a better way to handle this animation.

Comment: A code dump is not really helpful. Please set up a demonstration of minimal size to recreate your issue. This can be done on jsfiddle.net, codepen.io, jsbin.com, etc.

Comment: Up... The snippet is updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, several things wrong here.

1. Reason #1 that the animation was jerky is because you didn't specify an easing, so jQuery was using the default "swing" setting. What you want is "linear" because you want no easing at all, you want it to scroll up continuously at a steady rate like the Star Wars text does.
2. Reason #2 that the animation was jerky is because you were animating it up 20px, whereas your "suscrib" elements are 45px high. So you were only animating it halfway and then jumping it back to 0.
3. You had multiple DIVs with the id "suscrib". There should never be more than a single unique element with a given id in your document, use classes instead.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(function(){
       setInterval(function(){
          $(".slideshow ul").animate({marginTop:-45}, 2000, "linear", function(){
             $(this).css({marginTop:0}).find("li:last").after($(this).find("li:first"));
         })
       }, 2000);
    });

    
    });
```

```css
body { 
  background: url(img/1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.head {
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);
}

.users {
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding-top: 20px; 
 height: 400px;

 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);

}

.suscrib {
 height: 45px;
 font-size: 15px !important;
}


.slideshow {

   width: 200px;
   height: 370px;
   overflow: hidden;
   /*border: 3px solid #F2F2F2;*/
}

.slideshow ul {
    /* 4 images donc 4 x 100% */
   width: 100%;
   height: 200px;
   padding:0; margin:0;
   list-style: none;
}
.slideshow li {
   color: red;
   font-family: 'Satisfy';

   font-size: 15px;
}


.thanks {
 margin-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Dancing Script';
 font-size: 40px;
 color: red;
}

#ombre {
 box-shadow: 3px 3px 43px #000 !important;
}

h1 {
 padding-top: 80px;
 opacity: 1 !important;
 z-index: 10;
}

#logo {
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>


  
 <body>
  


   <div class="row">
       <div class="users col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5" id="ombre">
        <div class="slideshow col-lg-12 ">
         <ul id="pushme">
              <li> <div class='suscrib'> User user  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div class='suscrib'> User user2  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div class='suscrib'> User user3  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div class='suscrib'> User user4  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div class='suscrib'> User user  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div class='suscrib'> User user  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div class='suscrib'> User user  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div class='suscrib'> User user  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div class='suscrib'> User user  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div class='suscrib'> User user10  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div class='suscrib'> User user  </div>  </li>
              <li> <div class='suscrib'> User user  </div>  </li>
         </ul>
        </div>

       </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```